# Estimate execution time of a qiskit circuit?

Tags: qiskit, qiskit-runtime

I want to estimate the time a circuit written in qiskit would take if it were to run on a real quantum computer. I am really scared of writing something that is too slow and IBM then draining my bank account.

Is this even possible?

Thanks for any help!